# Not able to see .NET Core 2.1.4 even after installing SDK

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I had installed VS2017 Professional last year which came with ASP.NET Core version 1. I wanted to use features of Core version 2 so installed the latest SDK. Now in my Command line when I check version `dotnet --version` the it comes fine. Means it is Installed.

But when i try to start the a new project then the framework list it gives does not contain version 2 templates.

Please can anyone help me with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to update your Visual Studio 2017 version. Latest is as of today is **15.5.6**.

Comment: right now i have vs2017 preview v15.6 installed as well but i dont want it ..after RTM they will be all removed..

Comment: Hmm, VS 2017 15.5.6 is already in RTM. Could you please share a screenshot of your VS -> About,

Meantime, this should help as well,
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/windows-prerequisites?tabs=netcore2x